# aws autoscaling terminates old instance before starting new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, aws-cdk

I have a legacy application that needs to run on a single EC2 instance. I use the following asg

```js
const asg = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, `${stage}ASG`, {
  vpc,
  minCapacity: 1,
  maxCapacity: 1,
  launchTemplate,
  updatePolicy: autoscaling.UpdatePolicy.rollingUpdate({}),
  autoScalingGroupName: `${stage}ASG`,
  terminationPolicies: [autoscaling.TerminationPolicy.OLDEST_INSTANCE],
  healthCheck: autoscaling.HealthCheck.elb({
    grace: cdk.Duration.minutes(30),
  }),
});
```

However when updating the launch template, the asg first removes the single old instance before it starts up a new instance. This results in a significant downtime before the user script of the new instance has finished. I would like the asg to wait till the user script has finished and the loadbalancer health checks on the new instance pass before terminating the old instance.
How can I do this?

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html)

> Instances terminated before launch: When there is only one instance in the Auto Scaling group, starting an instance refresh can result in an outage. This is because Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling terminates an instance and then launches a new instance.

However they  don t say how to mitigate the issue in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but:

How are you triggering the update?  An Instance Refresh?  If so, an
[Instance Maintenance Policy](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-ec2-auto-scaling-ec2-instance-replacement/) is a new feature which just launched.  This allows you to set a Min Healthy Percentage on the ASG (or as part of your instance refresh).  Setting MinHealthyPercent to 100% means the group will now launch replacement instances before terminating old ones during most replacement processes.  There's also an accompanying [Blog post for more details](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-maintenance-policy-for-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling/)